# Difficulty in understanding isomorphism proof between 2 groups $Z_4$ and $U_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

What I got is (*please correct if anything is wrong*)

Given 2 groups $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $U_5$, proving isomorphism starts with proving there exist a bijection between 2 groups. Since there are same number of elements in them we can always construct a bijection.

But the mapping which preserves group structure should be bijective.

As both groups are cyclic, and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is with addition operation and $U_5$ is with multiplication operation.

I get that if one generator is mapped to another which could be $1\rightarrow2$, mapping is complete.

Mapping function could be defined as
$f(i) = a^i$

By this, required condition $f(a*b)=f(a)*f(b)$ is easily satisfied.

All this is understood intuitively. But how do I convey what generators are mapped and how do I prove there is bijection without multiplication or cayley table?

Comment: The two groups don't have the same cardinality, therefore they are not isomorphic.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have 4 elements viz. 0,1, 2, 3 and $U_5$ also have 4 elements viz. 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: $U(5)=(\mathbb{Z}/5)^*$ has $\phi(5)=4$ elements.

Comment: Sorry for me $U_5$ denotes the group of complex fifth roots of unity. You should define it if it is otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both groups have $4$ elements, and both groups are commutative. Furthermore all groups $U(p)$ are cyclic, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253196/help-to-prove-that-u-p-is-a-cyclic-group). Hence $U(5)$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$. Mapping a generator to a generator yields an isomorphism.

Comment: If we were to prove from 2 conditions mentioned above, then how do I prove bijection. Also mapping is from addition operation to multiplication. Which can be summarized as $f(i)=a^i$. How to clearly formulate this expression and prove its bijection?

Comment: What if we are not able to see that both are cyclic, then how?

Comment: Then it is also easy. Since commutative groups of order $4$ are only $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$, we just need to exclude the second - which follows from the fact, that not all elements in $U(5)$ have order $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Thing I can't understand is bijective mapping. Can you also show what mapping is between these groups. Or is product table only way to show mapping?

Comment: Indeed, check that $f(n)=a^n$ is a group isomorphism. Do we have $f(n+m)=f(n)f(m)$?

Comment: yes that is satisfied but how is it one to one and onto?

Comment: also, it is not very clear which element is mapped to which using $f(n)=a^n$

Comment: If $f(n)=1$, then $n=0$. Hence $f$ is injective. Every injective map between finite sets is also surjective. The map $f(n)$ clearly maps $0$ to $a^0=1$, $1$ to $a^1$, ..., until $p-1$ to $a^{p-1}$. So where is the difficulty?

Comment: I'm new to this kind of maths and it appears that representation and language is half the work. I could see the mapping is bijective but writing that was not clear. Writing $\mathbb{Z}_4$ as set of powers of $a$ and then showing mapping between them to ${0, 1, 2...}$ is articulate enough.                                 But one question in context of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $U_5$, what exactly is $a$? Is it 1?

Comment: The cyclic group $C_p=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots ,a^{p-1}\}$ means that $a$ is a group element, not a number. Like for polynomials, $x^2+3x+2$ does not mean that $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly give an isomorphism:

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$ such that $\phi(n)=2^n$. Then $\phi(a+b)=2^{a+b}=2^a2^b=\phi(a)\phi(b)$.

- Assume $\phi(n)=1$, then $2^n\equiv_51$ so $n\equiv_40$, since $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$. $\phi$ is injective.
- If $a\in\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$ then $a=2^m$, so $\phi(m)=a$. $\phi$ is surjective.