# Is this a(nother) proof of the cyclicity of the multiplicative group of the integers modulo $p$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-fields, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

The (finite abelian) multiplicative group of the integers modulo a prime $p$ can't have a subgroup isomorphic to $C_q\times C_q$, for some prime $q$, because in that case $x^q=1$ would have $q^2$ solutions, which is not possible for a well-known lemma on the field ${\bf{Z}}/(p)$. Is it correct? Does it follow from [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195513/1092170) that the group is cyclic? (I know that this group *is* cyclic, so I'm asking whether this is a valid proof of it.)

Comment: I believe everything you say is correct! (well, $x^q=1$ would have $q^2$ solutions)

Comment: Thank you @GregMartin. Indeed, I forgot the unit. Edited.

Comment: Do you mean the group of units of the ring $\Bbb Z/p$? Some people write $U(p)$ or $(\Bbb Z/p)^{\times}$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253196/help-to-prove-that-u-p-is-a-cyclic-group) for proofs, or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988847/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-up-for-prime-p-is-cyclic-using-only-group-t).

Comment: Yes, @DietrichBurde, I mean that group. I think this collects them (proofs) all: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a nice collection.

Comment: Infact writing the group with primitive roots helps and make out a different proof.

Comment: Since p and q are prime